# magento 2 css js not load in iis server

Tags: magento2

I have magento2 installed in IIS server (version 7), problem is not load any js and css.
I already have mod_rewrite is on and it is cheeked by this script.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['IIS_UrlRewriteModule']))
{
    $mod_rewrite = "TRUE";
}
else
{
    $mod_rewrite = " FALSE";
}
echo $mod_rewrite;
```

Its return me true.
I also update the `app/etc/di.xml` and change

`Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`

to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

then delete _requirejs folder in `pub\static` (only one dir `_requirejs` is there) but not work at all.

I also try with this command

```
php dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View/deploy.php
```

but in my installation there is no `View/location` folder in same path, path just end with `magentoroot\dev\tools\Magento\Tools`

I also run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and this also

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

but both not work and not return anything.